# Magento - getUrl for custom extension

Tags: url, magento

I have developed a extension and want a link the url to my custom extension.

This is what i have done

```
Mage::getUrl('productdisplay/index/list');
```

but it is returning me

http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin_productdisplay/index/list/

"admin_" is getting added to the url

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the module's `config.xml`. Please add the contents of that file to your question.

Comment: @clockworkgeek
below link you can find the content of the confic.xml file
http://pastebin.com/erZuqECW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [config file](http://pastebin.com/erZuqECW) (thanks for posting) you have this:

```
<routers>
    <productdetails>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>MYMODULE_ProductDetails</module>
            <frontName>admin_productdetails</frontName>
        </args>
    </productdetails>
</routers>
```

Simply change the `frontName` to `productdetails`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i was banging my head for this problem :)

Comment: You're welcome MagDev. To aid others who might be searching for the same answer please click the 'accepted' checkmark to the left.